# create notebook page ui in android

Tags: android

I want to create textview on notebook page with equal spacing between each line just above the notebook page line.The following link http://www.photos-public-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/yellow-notebook-paper-texture.jpg
and in mdpi and ldpi, will the textview spacing still hold good with the background image as drawable?

Please let me know how to proceed.
Thanks in Advance.